# linphone Android.mk file Android

Tags: android, linphone

I'm new using linphone and using Android NDK

I have the following problem, I have downloaded the git repository of linphone and what I want to do is to build it,

I'm using windows cmd to do that using the following command :

```
D:\aelsayed\Android_SDK_and_NDK\ndk\android-ndk-r9b>bash ndk-build D:/aelsayed/a
ndroid-work/linphone-android
```

but I'm always have the following error :

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: D:\aelsayed\Androi
d_SDK_and_NDK\ndk\android-ndk-r9b/jni/Android.mk
/d/aelsayed/Android_SDK_and_NDK/ndk/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/add-application.m
k:171: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I have the following configuration

in Makefile :

NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname `D:/aelsayed/Android_SDK_and_NDK/ndk/android-ndk-r9b`)
SDK_PATH=$(shell dirname `D:/aelsayed/Android_SDK_and_NDK/sdk/tools`)
SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS_PATH=$(shell dirname `D:/aelsayed/Android_SDK_and_NDK/sdk/platform-tools`)

in Application.mk :

```
APP_PROJECT_PATH := 'C:/cygwin/home/ActelMe/D;C:/cygwin/aelsayed/android-work/linphone-android;
linphone-root-dir:=$(APP_PROJECT_PATH)

APP_BUILD_SCRIPT:=$(linphone-root-dir)/jni/Android.mk
```

B.N: I have used cygwin to get application path and it is not working and also when I use the absolute path without using cygwin I have the same error

B.N. I have tried also to create jni folder in the path of ndk and it works but it failed to run the submodules

Please any one can help in this error, or tell me what if the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a lot of searching, I have send mail to linphone forums and I got the following reply :

Building linphone is not supported on windows machine and you have to build it on mac or linux

Comment: Why is that you always ask questions and answer it yourself?

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia : may be because no one answer the question and when i found the answer or the cause of the problem I want to share it with others who may face the same problem, and also to keep the data I found in my knowledge base to help me again if I face the same problem

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer and I am facing same problem from two days.